# Navigation bar: On hover, my menu raises a submenu, but when the user tries to navigate to the submenu, they tend to interact with another nav item

Tags: css, reactjs, navigation

This is more of a "point me in the right direction" question. I remember seeing an article about this a while ago, but for the life of me, the Google query is eluding me. Let me set the stage:

[picture of scenario:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z89uu.png)
Horizontal nav bar, dark blue is currently selected, red sub-menu. When the user's mouse follows the black arrow, it crosses over the light-blue nav item, which opens the light-blue sub-menu.

I would like to keep the dark-blue sub-menu open.

I think this is platform independent, but fyi, I'm using React.

An option is to use timeouts, but I remember there being a solution about tracking the mouse position to gauge user intent.

edit: further research is pointing me towards "menu aiming", but I am unsure of the implications.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to accomplish this is to put an is_mouse_over variable that turns true on the mouseover event and false on the mouseleave event.
In the same mouseover event callback, place a setTimeout that waits the desired number of milliseconds to determine that the user is attempting to open the menu, and after those ms, call the function that opens the menu only if is_mouse_over is true. To close it you must do the same in the mouseleave. That is, put a setTimeout to close it, and before closing it check that is_mouse_over is false.
The implementation should be tailored to your react project, but in vanilla javascript it would look like this:

```
function openSubmenu() {
  // Your implementation
}

function closeSubmenu() {
  // Your implementation
}

time_to_confirm_user_intent = 350
mouse_is_over_nav_item = false

navItem.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    mouse_is_over_nav_item = true
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (mouse_is_over_nav_item)
            openSubMenu()
    }, time_to_confirm_user_intent)
})

navItem.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    mouse_is_over_nav_item = false
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!mouse_is_over_nav_item)
            closeSubMenu()
    }, time_to_confirm_user_intent)
})
```